# How to re-render a page to get its default values in React js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a page that contains a lot of components such as `TextField`s and `combobox`es. When a button, assume `Clean`, is clicked, I want to refresh the current page to set each component with their default values and also set `state` to `initial state`. When I tried `window.location.reload()`, it refreshes the whole page and user needs to login again.

I tried `forceUpdate()` but it preserves the current state of the page.

I also tried, it might be absurd I am newbie, to push history as below,

```
this.props.history.push("/");
this.props.history.push("new-record");
```

But this didn't work. Page stayed same.

How can I handle this?

Comment: You can give your components a `key` prop, and then change the `key` when you want to mount an entirely new instance of that component. This way the state will be reset to what it was initially.

Answer (score 1):

try something similar for state reset:

```
const initialState = { name: 'React' }

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = initialState
  }

resetState=()=>{
this.setState(initialState)
}


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <button
      onClick={this.resetState}>reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Good one. But I need to set all component values to state in this case whether it is needed or not. I will stick to a more flexible solution for a while. If this is the only way, I will take this one. thank you.

Comment: yep, when you make this reset on container component, all child-components re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with code: 
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/tramwaj157/pen/qymOMy)

There is a local state with *defaultInputValue* and *currentValue*:

```
  this.state = {
    defaultInputValue: defaultValue,
    currentValue: defaultValue
  }
```

*setDefault* function restore default values:

```
setDefault = () => {
   this.setState({currentValue: this.state.defaultInputValue});
}
```